# python - PyQt5 Emits Signal only in the class that the emit statement is in (Intended behaviour?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been racking my brain over this issue for a week now. Whenever I emit a signal it seems to stay local to the class where it is called in.

My objective is to emit a signal in one class and receive it in multiple. Basically im trying to a emit a signal to another class to carry over data.

My problem might stem from using QStackedWidget, every single stackoverflow thread or youtube  video I have seen about signals/slots has not used QStackedWidget.

Below is my code, it showcases that even though I emit to the same signal, the slot is only activated when the signal is in the class where the slot is.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
import sys


# Class that holds the signal
class communication(QObject):
    GotFilePath = pyqtSignal(str)


# Class for first page
class DataLoadedPage(QWidget):

    # Initilize
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataLoadedPage, self).__init__()
        # import signal class
        self.communication = communication()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Label
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("First page")
        self.label.move(50,50)
        
        # Button
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText('Next screen')


        # Connect to signal from signal class and print which page its on
        self.communication.GotFilePath.connect(self.somethingrandom)

        # Connect button to emitter and change page
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.mouseclick)



    def somethingrandom(self, emitted):
      print('First') # <------------- Difference

    def mouseclick(self):
        self.communication.GotFilePath.emit("Emitted")
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1) # Go to second page



# Class for second page
class DataLoadedPage2(QWidget):

    # Initilize
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataLoadedPage2, self).__init__()

        # import signal class
        self.communication = communication()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Label
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Second page")
        self.label.move(50,50)

        # Button
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText('Previous screen')



        # Connect to signal from signal class and print which page its on
        self.communication.GotFilePath.connect(self.somethingrandom)

        # Connect button to emitter and change page
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.mouseclick)



    def somethingrandom(self, Emitted):
      print('second') # <--------------- Difference

    def mouseclick(self):
        self.communication.GotFilePath.emit("Emitted")
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()-1) # Go to first page



# define widget
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()

# Define pages
frontpage = DataLoadedPage()
secondpage = DataLoadedPage2()

# Add pages to widget
widget.addWidget(frontpage)
widget.addWidget(secondpage)

# Launch application
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Feel free to try out the code, it does function

Comment: I'm afraid you're a bit confused about how signals work (and probably also about the difference between classes and instances). Can you explain what is your *final* purpose? Right now your code is too generic, and knowing your needs might help us to provide a more detailed answer that would help you better understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While signals are *created* as class attributes, they are actually *bound* to an instance of a QObject.

In your code you are creating *two* different instances of `communication`, and since you connected that instance signal to the instance of the class in which you created it, you will only get *that* signal.

If you want a "broadcast" signal, then you should create a *single* instance of the class for that signal and use it in any sender or receiver instance that will use it:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, 
    QStackedWidget, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal


class Communication(QObject):
    gotFilePath = pyqtSignal(str)


class DataLoadedPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, communication):
        super().__init__()

        self.communication = communication
        self.communication.gotFilePath.connect(self.somethingrandom)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel('First page')
        self.b1 = QPushButton('Next screen')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.b1)

        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.mouseclick)

    def somethingrandom(self, emitted):
        print('First')

    def mouseclick(self):
        self.communication.gotFilePath.emit('Emitted')
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)


class DataLoadedPage2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, communication):
        super().__init__()

        self.communication = communication
        self.communication.gotFilePath.connect(self.somethingrandom)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel('Second page')
        self.b1 = QPushButton('Previous screen')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.b1)

        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.mouseclick)

    def somethingrandom(self, Emitted):
        print('Second')

    def mouseclick(self):
        self.communication.gotFilePath.emit('Emitted')
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() - 1)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QStackedWidget()

communication = Communication()
frontpage = DataLoadedPage(communication)
secondpage = DataLoadedPage2(communication)

widget.addWidget(frontpage)
widget.addWidget(secondpage)

widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With the code above, the communication object is created outside of any class, and used as a parameter in the `__init__` of each page, so that an instance attribute can be created for its reference, and finally connected to each instance method. Any time the signal is emitted, each connected ("subscribed") function will be called.

Note that this behavior is rarely needed, and you might actually need to use signals to communicate *between* instances.

For this, there is actually no need for a separate class for the signal, as you can add to each page class (since QWidget inherits from QObject).

In this case, since the connections are bidirectional, they have to be done after both instances are created. You either create a function in each class that actually connects the signal, or you do that *externally*.

```py
class DataLoadedPage(QWidget):
    gotFilePath = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel('First page')
        self.b1 = QPushButton('Next screen')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.b1)

        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.mouseclick)

    def somethingrandom(self, emitted):
        print('First')

    def mouseclick(self):
        self.gotFilePath.emit('Emitted')
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)


class DataLoadedPage2(QWidget):
    gotFilePath = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel('Second page')
        self.b1 = QPushButton('Previous screen')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.b1)

        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.mouseclick)

    def somethingrandom(self, Emitted):
        print('Second')

    def mouseclick(self):
        self.gotFilePath.emit('Emitted')
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() - 1)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QStackedWidget()

frontpage = DataLoadedPage()
secondpage = DataLoadedPage2()

frontpage.gotFilePath.connect(secondpage.somethingrandom)
secondpage.gotFilePath.connect(frontpage.somethingrandom)

widget.addWidget(frontpage)
widget.addWidget(secondpage)

widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With the code above, "Second" will be shown when the button of the first page is clicked, and vice versa.

<sup>Some further notes: 1. I took the liberty to fix some naming, style and syntax to better follow the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) which is important for code readability, and also unified the import style (generally, you should either import individual classes or the submodule containing them, not both); 2. you should **always** use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), as shown above; 3. you're probably following a youtube tutorial ("Code first with Hala") that is known to provide ***a lot*** of terrible suggestions and bad practices, I strongly suggest you to *ignore* it.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! You're right im entirely new to pyqt and OOP.  The reason my code was so generic is because my actual project uses .ui files to draw the ui. I thought I would make it easier to make a generic example. Thats also the reason why I didnt use layout managers. Can you recommend any sources for good practises in pyqt? I would love to learn more about it.

Comment: @BlueFire the fact that you use ui files or not is irrelevant, your code is "conceptually generic": it's not clear what you want to achieve and what is your final purpose. Most good practices come from experience and various sources (documentation, [tutorials](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials), etc.), so I can only suggest you to *keep practicing*, challenge yourself with test projects that mimic real life requirements for a program, read questions here on SO and try to answer them on your own (even if you don't actually provide an answer).